# Does .shape on a numpy array detect nested arrays, or nested lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a 100x3 dataframe of strings in numpy, but this question concerns one column, so a 100x1 pandas Series.

I convert it to a 100x8x8x1 array of chess boards with this function:

```
def boardToNPArray(x):
    x = chess.Board(x)
    x=x.__str__()
    x = x.split("\n")
    for n in range(len(x)):
        x[n] = np.array(x[n].split()).reshape(8,1)
    return np.array(x)

asdf['FEN'] = asdf['FEN'].apply(lambda x : boardToNPArray(x))
```

Which should make it a dataframe of length 100 containing chess board numpy arrays of 8x8x1.

I then do asdf['FEN'].values to convert the dataframe to a numpy array.

```
asdf['FEN'].values
# Which returns
array([array([[['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['k'],
        ['.'],
        ['.']],

       [['R'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['p'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['P'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['K'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.']],

       [['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['.'],
        ['r'],
        ['.']]], dtype='<U1'),
# This is one 8x8x1 entry in the
```

Theoretically, this should arrive at my goal--a 100x8x8x1 numpy array.
Yet, when running

```
asdf['FEN'].shape
```

It returns

```
(100,)
```

And when running

```
asdf['FEN'][0].shape
```

It returns

```
(8,8,1)
```

And type() of both is a numpy.ndarray
Why isn't this a 100x8x8x1 array?

Comment: There's a difference between a 1d object dtype array containing lists or arrays, and a n-d array of string or numeric dtype.  A pandas Series is 1-d, even if object dtype.

Comment: `shape` does not reach through the object dtype 'wall'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying `numpy.stack` to the result of `Series.values`:

```
s = pd.Series(map(np.array,map(list,['asdf','qwer'])))
np.stack(s.values).shape # (2,4)
```